# Error in first line of polymer custom component

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm getting started with Polymer. I'm trying develop new Polymer web component, but google chrome is raising error.

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="texto-principal">

    <template>
        <!-- bind to the "owner" property -->
        This is
        <b>{{owner}}</b>'s configurable-name-tag element.
    </template>

    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: "texto-principal",
            properties: {
                // declare the owner property
                owner: {
                    type: String,
                    value: "Daniel"
                }
            }
        });
    </script>

</dom-module>
```

Google Chrome is raising: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` in first line.
How can I solve this?

Comment: For starters the `id` attribute of the `dom-module` **must** match the name of the `is` property when registering the element with Polymer.

Answer (score 3):

The `id` of the `dom-module` should match the `is` property in the JavaScript when registering the element with Polymer.

And then import it in a separate file:

```
<link rel="import" href="/path/to/texto-principal.html>
```

and then to use the component:

```
<texto-principal></texto-principal>
```

you can also change the value of `owner` by using it as an attribute:

```
<texto-principal owner="John"></texto-principal>
```

Comment: This was also a problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I already found the point.

I'm trying polymer with asp.net mvc5, and I was not importing polymer library in the right way.

Comment: I'm the author. The problem described was happening because Polymer was not correctly referrenced by my project.